# Asp.net core: Selenium doesn't see geckodriver in current directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, automated-tests, geckodriver

web api core 2.0 project doesn't see geckodriver.exe
How can I fix it?!

I created a asp.net core 2.0 web api project.
I put a geckodriver.exe to directory with project, I changed "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always".

This is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists("geckodriver.exe"))
            {
               throw new Exception("error"); 
            }

            using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://gooogle.com");
            }
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

When I start my project, I get exception message

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The geckodriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.'

I wonder why .net framework mvc application with same code works well!

My question is: how to fix my problem? I can't find a solution on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver is copied to the output directory. Just use the following line of code:
`var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))`

This happens because the NuGet packages for .NET Core projects are loaded from a global place instead of the packages folder of the .NET Framework projects. To fix it, we need to specify the path to the execution folder.
(source: https://www.automatetheplanet.com/webdriver-dotnetcore2/)

Comment: use <PublishGeckoDriver>true</PublishGeckoDriver>
https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-geckodriver

Answer (score 2):

Copy driver.exe to following path:

```
C:\Users\[userName]\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\3.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Unfortunately this solution is not crossplatform